# How to calculate the lowest common term in two offset sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $a$ be a sequence of the squares for all natural numbers.

So:   $a = \{0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2,5^2,...\} = \{ 0, 1, 4, 9,16,25,...\}$

Is there a way to find out when the equation below will be true without checking each of the terms?

$x + a_i = a_j$

where $x,i,j \in \mathbb{N}  $

*For example:*
Let $x = 23$, then:
$23 + 121 = 144$
so $i=11$ and $j=12$

Edit: To clarify I would like to calculate $i$ and $j$ from $x$.

Comment: Odd numbers can be made easily by $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$

Comment: $x$ can be any natural number which is not $2$ more than a multiple of $4$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$, consider all the factorisations of $x$ as $y \times z$ where $y$ and $z$ have the same parity, i.e. both even or both odd, and $y \ge z$; this will be possible if and only if $x$ is not $2$ more than a multiple of $4$

Then since $\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{y-z}{2}\right)^2 = yz$ we have $x + \left(\frac{y-z}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)^2$

In your example, with $x=23$ we only have $23\times 1$ giving $23 + \left(\frac{23-1}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{23+1}{2}\right)^2$

For another example, if $x=45$ then we have $45 \times 1 = 15 \times 3 = 9 \times 5$ so we get:

- $45 + 22^2 = 23^2$
- $45 + 6^2 = 9^2$
- $45 + 2^2 = 7^2$

You want $i=\left(\frac{y-z}{2}\right)^2$ and $j=\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)^2$

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a pattern, in fact, letting $i=n, j=n+1$ and $x=2n+1$ yields:
$$a_n+2n+1=a_{n+1}$$
This can easily be confirmed by letting $a_n=n^2$, indeed $n^2+2n+1=(n^2+1)^2$.